# Generalization of arithmetic to analytic :

Tags: analysis, soft-question, arithmetic, analytic-number-theory

Euler generalized factorial function (arithmetic) to gamma function (analytic).

Classical Combinatorics is generalized to analytic combinatorics by various authors ( mainly P. Flajolet)

Analytic number theory has same goal of generalizing arithmetic view of primes to analytic nature .

> > Question : what are some other significant  generalization of arithmetic nature to analytic nature in mathematics ?

Comment: Analytic function and generating function are quite the same thing, thus many problems in number theory have an analytic counterpart.

Comment: @renus thank you for comment , but many  of arithmetic -analytic correlation remains to be proven . I'm asking for the examples of  proved ones.